# ¿Cómo puedo saber cuál es el valor que más se repite en un vector?

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero saber cómo podría saber cual es el valor que más se repite en un vector al presionar un button; en este caso el valor que más se repite en la variable "lista".

```js
let lista=[2,4,2,3,1];
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="practica.css">
</head>
<body>
<div>
   <button id="boton"></button>
</div>
<script src="practica.js"> 
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aca te paso un ejemplo que hace lo que pedis.

1- Usamos la funcion reduce para recorrer todo el array e ir guardando en un objeto `cantEle` los pares "elemento:cantidad", en este caso `cantEle` seria `{1: 1, 2: 3, 3: 2, 4: 1}` (porque modifique el array original con el que hiciste la pregunta, para evaluar otras opciones)

2- Teniendo lo mas importante, ahora recorremos uno a uno los elementos del objeto `cantEle`, y guardamos el **maximo** valor en la variable `maxValue`, àl mismo momento que guardamos la **key** correspondiente a este valor.

3- Finalmente imprimimos el resultado!

```
const lista=[2,4,2,3,2,3,1];

const cantEle = lista.reduce((contadorEle, elemento) => {
    contadorEle[elemento] = (contadorEle[elemento] || 0) +1;
    return contadorEle; 
    }, {});

var maxValue = 0;
var myKey = '';

for (key in cantEle)
{
     if (cantEle[key] > maxValue)
     {
          maxValue = cantEle[key];  
          myKey = key; 

     }
}

console.log( 'El numero que mas se repite es el '+myKey+ ' que aparece '+maxValue+' veces.'   );
```

Answer (score 2):

Hay muchas formas de hacer esto. Esta es una de ellas, utiliza un objeto donde guardamos el conteo de cada numero y luego regresamos la llave del objeto con el valor mas grande.

```
let lista=[2,4,2,3,1];

function masRepetidoList(lista){
  let result = {}
  for (var i =0; i< lista.length; i++){
      if( !(lista[i].toString() in result)){
         result[lista[i].toString()] = 1

      }
      else{
        result[lista[i].toString()] += 1
      }
  }
  let max = -1;
  let maxkey = '';
  for(key in result){
    if (result[key] > max) {
       max = result[key];
       maxkey = key;
    }
  }
  return parseInt(maxkey)
}

max = masRepetidoList(lista);
console.log(max)
```

Comment: Me podrías explicar la segunda parte de key y todo eso, no entiendo bien para que funciona.

Answer (score 2):

Creo que esta es la manera mas sencilla de lograr tu objetivo, favor de notificarme que opción has seleccionado y espero te ayude. Agradeceria tu Feedback.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function defineArray() {
        var lista = [2, 4, 2, 3, 1];
        var cleanLista = new Set(lista.sort());
        var cnt = 0;
        var valCnt = 0;
        var lastNumber;
        cleanLista.forEach(function verify(E) {
            cnt = 0;
            lista.forEach(function countDuplicate(F) {
                if (E == F) {
                    cnt = cnt + 1;
                }
            });
            if (cnt > valCnt) {
                valCnt = cnt;
                lastNumber = E;
            }
        });
        alert(lastNumber);
    }
</script>
```